# Display a flickering message when a mail is being sent

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

**Objective**: I need to display a flickering button-text namely "Sending", when an Email *is being* sent, after send button has been clicked.

**Issue:** Sending of an email takes some time. In the mean time, the form gets frozen. The flickering message gets displayed, *after* the message has been sent.

**Approaches Tried:** 
1) Used two timers one for displaying a flickering label-message, the other for sending.
2) Used Application.DoEvents()

**Code:**

```
 private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


                TimrSending.Start();
                OleDbDataReader hold = cdbc.connectDB("SELECT UserID, PassWord, EmailID from Tbl_RegisteredUser where UserID='" + TxtUserID.Text + "' and AF=true");
                hold.Read();
                SendMailNew(hold[0].ToString(), hold[1].ToString(), hold[2].ToString());
                cdbc.disconectDB();
                MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully! \n Please check your registered Email address for the password");
                cdbc.disconectDB();
                this.Close();
                //Application.DoEvents();
                this.TimrSending.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                cdbc.disconectDB();
                this.TimrSent.Stop();
                BtnSend.Text = "Send";
                MessageBox.Show("Message sending failed! \n Exeption" + e.ToString(), "Email Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK); 
            }

        }

        private void TimrSending_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (flag == true)
            {
                BtnSend.Text = "Sending";
                flag = false;
                //Application.DoEvents();
            }
            else
            {
                BtnSend.Text = "..Sending..";
                flag = true;
                //Application.DoEvents();
            }

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

Comment: In order to not block your UI thread, run the 'flickering-message' task on a separate thread. `BackgroundWorker` will be very useful for your case (you can also take advantage of its `ReportProgress` event).
Read more [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What is the problem with timers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned, the `SendMailNew()` function is, presumably, blocking the UI thread so you're not seeing the intended results from your `Timer'.

There are a few ways to skin this cat. In my opinion, an easy, straight forward, and tested way to patch your code is to implement a `BackgroundWorker`. By doing so, you can throw your `SendMailNew()` function on a thread and toggle your UI controls without issue. Some code:

```
private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {            
        BackgroundWorker SendMail = new BackgroundWorker()
        {
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };

        SendMail.DoWork += SendMail_DoWork;
        SendMail.RunWorkerCompleted += SendMail_RunWorkerCompleted;

        TimrSending.Start();
        OleDbDataReader hold = cdbc.connectDB("SELECT UserID, PassWord, EmailID from Tbl_RegisteredUser where UserID='" + TxtUserID.Text + "' and AF=true");
        hold.Read();

        List<string> parameters = new List<string>() {hold[0].ToString(), hold[1].ToString(), hold[2].ToString()};
        SendMail.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        cdbc.disconectDB();
        this.TimrSent.Stop();
        BtnSend.Text = "Send";
        MessageBox.Show("Message sending failed! \n Exeption" + e.ToString(), "Email Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK); 
    }
}

private void SendMail_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> args = (List<string>) e.Argument;

    try
    {
        SendMailNew(args[0], args[1], args[2]);

        e.Result = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        e.Result = false;
    }
}

void SendMail_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{                
    if(e.Result)
    {
        cdbc.disconectDB();
        MessageBox.Show("Message sent successfully! \n Please check your registered Email address for the password");
        cdbc.disconectDB();
        this.Close();
        //Application.DoEvents();
        this.TimrSending.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        // Fail
    }        
}

private void TimrSending_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     BtnSend.Text = flag ? "Sending" : "..Sending..";
     flag = !flag;
}
```

All the finalizing code is now in `RunWorkerCompleted()`, which runs after the `SendMailNew()` function returns from the separate thread started by `DoWork()`. I also slightly optimized the `TimerSending_Tick()` method, but functionally does the same thing.

EDIT: In good practice, you probably want to check to make `SendMailNew()` executes successfully. The best way to do this is to make use of the `Result` parameter provided to you in the `DowWorkEventArgs` and `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`, since your main thread won't be able to trap errors from SendMailNew. Updated code accordingly. If you need to inspect the error, return the message in e.Result.

Comment: Thank you Glace,
It took me a while to understand the meaning of those functions. But now thanks to you, I got some knowledge on threading. Last but not the least, your answer was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @VAR not a problem. Threading isn't an easy topic; The Backgroundworker gives you a nice, structured way to utilize the advantages of a Thread without the headaches of managing them. Best of luck, and if you need any further explanations on the above solution I would be happy to help.

Comment: Well, I did have doubts with that "list" thing. I did try eliminating the entire list thing by inserting the "Select & hold" part within the SendMail_DoWork, but it didn't work that well. Dunno why.
Anyways thank you & sorry for the trouble :)